# How to ensure process remains running when my local internet is down

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Currently I SSH to my EC2 instance from a local machine. If my internet goes down, the SSH connection goes down, along with the process running inside the terminal.

I'd like to run a process on EC2 without my internet affecting it's running.

Does EC2 Instance Connect provide this? If not, is there anything else I can do/use?

EDIT: This is for Linux

Comment: Run it as a service on the EC2 instance. You didn't indicate if it's Windows, Amazon Linux, Ubuntu etc. or what the nature of the app is (shell script, Python app, Node.js app etc.) so it's hard to provide more info.

Comment: EC2 instance is the same as VM machine, server VM like LInux, Windows, and MacOS. If you meant this "[process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing))", then it won't be affected by your internet connection disruption. The same as you SSH to Linux server and then exited the connection from its server.

Comment: Obviously on Linux you can use tools such as tmux or screen to maintain your SSH session across disconnects and that might be suitable for an ad hoc script but it won't be appropriate for an actual 24x7 app (where you would use something like systemctl, systemd, pm2 etc.)

Comment: Why is this tagged with `amazon-ecs` when you make no mention of using ECS in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this EC2 is a Linux instance, it sounds like the issue could be a SIGHUP signal caused by the connection going down. You can use the `nohup` command to ignore hang up signals. Combine this with `&` to run your process in the background, and you should be able to safely close the shell without affecting the running process. For example:

```bash
nohup yourcommand --youroptions &
```

Comment: Thanks. After I reconnect via SSH, is there any way of rediscovering the terminal output, or i'd just have to output to a file and tail it?

Comment: You can view the processes currently running in the background with ```jobs``` and bring them back to the foreground with ```fg```. However this is no longer possible after you close or disconnect from the shell, as the "foreground" shell no longer exists. You could use a screen multiplexer like tmux or screen to achieve this instead.